# parse array of dates string in javascript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have array of datestring that consist of date and time and I would like to split the date time as there is '@' in between and combine them together in an array. I have developed the below script and find that I am getting only the last date value.

```
dates = ['1-12-21 @ 12:31 AM', '1-26-21 @ 09:45 AM', '12-14-20 @ 2:22 PM']
for(var i =0; i<dates.length;i++) {
  var array = new Array();
  array = dates[i].split('@');
  var newDate = new Date(array[0] + " " + array[1]);
  return newDate;}
```

I am getting the final value of 12-14-20 2:22 PM and not an array of dates. Instead I would like to get the array of date strings to date values.

I am new in javascript and so slowly catching up things.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution:

You can declare an empty array and push parsed dates into that:

Sample Code:

```
function dateParse() {
  var dates = ['1-12-21 @ 12:31 AM', '1-26-21 @ 09:45 AM', '12-14-20 @ 2:22 PM'];
  var newDate = [];
  for(var i =0; i<dates.length;i++) {
    var array = new Array();
    array = dates[i].split('@');
    newDate.push(new Date(array[0] + " " + array[1]));
  }
  return newDate;
}
```

### Results:

[image]

### Reference:

[Array.prototype.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

Answer (score 0):

by having a return statemet, I assume this code is inside a function

if you put the return statement inside the for, it will exit returning the newDate value.

put the return outside the for statement, and push the dates in an array

```
function getDates()
{
  dates = ['1-12-21 @ 12:31 AM', '1-26-21 @ 09:45 AM', '12-14-20 @ 2:22 PM']
  var datesArray= new Array();
  for(var i =0; i<dates.length;i++) {
     var array = new Array();
     array = dates[i].split('@');
     var newDate = new Date(array[0] + " " + array[1]);
     datesArray.push(newDate)
  
  }
  return datesArray;
}
```